# php insert text file to mysql encoding

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have to import the data from a .txt file to mySQL db.

When I open txt with notepad the file is written in DOS/Windows ANSI (encode in ANSI).
When I open it with AkelPad I get the info that the file is encoded in 1253 (ANSI-Greek)

I import data with the below code

```
$myFile = "Bill.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData1 = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
$theData = str_replace("'","#",$theData1);
$theData = iconv('cp1253','UTF-8',$theData);
$data = (filesize($myFile))/156;
fclose($fh);
$line = 0;

mysql_query("TRUNCATE Bill");
for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $data; $counter++) {
  $Barcode[counter] = substr($theData, ($line+0), 10);
  $BuildingCode[counter] = substr($theData, ($line+10), 5);
  $BuildingAddress[counter] = substr($theData, ($line+14), 40);
  $FlatName[counter] = substr($theData, ($line+54), 50);
  $FlatDescription[counter] = substr($theData, ($line+104), 8);
  $EntrySeason[counter] = substr($theData, ($line+112), 23);
  $Period[counter] = substr($theData, ($line+135), 11);
  $Amountint = substr($theData, ($line+146), 7);
  $Amountdec = substr($theData, ($line+153), 2);
  $Amount[counter] = $Amountint.'.'.$Amountdec;

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO Bill (Id, Code, Address, Name, Description, EntrySeason, Period, Revenue) 
  VALUES ('$Barcode[counter]', '$BuildingCode[counter]', '$BuildingAddress[counter]', '$FlatName[counter]', '$FlatDescription[counter]', '$EntrySeason[counter]', '$Period[counter]', '$Amount[counter]')");

  $line = $counter * 156;
}
```

When I read the above data with the code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Bill ORDER BY Id ASC"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$i=0;
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$i=$i+1;
echo $i." - ".$row['Id']. " - ". $row['Code']. " - ". $row['Address']. " - ". $row['Name']. " - ". $row['Description']. " - ". $row['EntrySeason']. " - ". $row['Period']. " - ". $row['Revenue'].'<br>';
```

I receive Greek letters. When I check db with phpmyadmin all the Greek entries are like this chars `ÃÅÙÑÃ.ÃÅÍÍÇÌÁÔÁ 39Á`

If I try to insert the entrys from mysql to sqlite the letters are these `ÃÅÙÑÃ.ÃÅÍÍÇÌÁÔÁ 39Á`

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that could be wrong

1) Are you sure that you are using the UTF-8 database, table, column in database where you are trying to save the data?

2) Do you run mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); before you run the select/update to the database?

If you are doing both right, then I would suggest you to debug this in bigger detail.

3) Try to specify one character in the txt file and try to echo the ord($str{xxx}) before and after the iconv function and check if the binary data is really UTF-8 correctly encoded.

Comment: I try the following I echo ord of the first letter from my txt and i receive 208. After iconv iconv('CP1253','UTF-8',$theData); i receive 206... What have to do?

Comment: What is the correct character. Should it be 206 or 208? And what do you get when you try to get this from the database (again in ord)?